# Different statistics on different accounts on Stack Exchange family sites

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I have an account here, and on other sites of Stack Exchange, but on each site I have separate statistics, as if it were separate accounts.

Is this OK, or I should merge those accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to have different statics on each SE site. Look at any user that has accounts on different SE sites, and you'll see that in each one of them they have different rep and different badges.

The badges and reputation you receive count for that site.

Answer (score 0):

The accounts are already "merged" under one global [Network Account](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).

In that network account you can see list of all your accounts in Stack Exchange, plus your activity on each, all in one place.